# expression when sum have minus number then show 0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have textbox with expression

```
=Sum(Fields!servicetotal.Value, "Service") - Sum(Fields!servicefee.Value, "Service")
```

Got the correct result.

If the result number is negative, then I need to show (display) 0.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I think  it will work around by add another textbox and give it iif expression. I'm ok with it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IIF(
     Sum(Fields!servicetotal.Value, "Service") - Sum(Fields!servicefee.Value, "Service")<0,
    0,
    Sum(Fields!servicetotal.Value, "Service") - Sum(Fields!servicefee.Value, "Service")
    )
```